# Read return parameters by name from stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

Is there a way to read some custom return parameters from a stored procedure by name in C#? The iterative way works like this:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (rdr.HasRows)
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        if (rdr[0] != null)
        {
            string PARAM1 = rdr[0].ToString();
        }
        if (rdr[1] != null)
        {
            string PARAM2 = rdr[1].ToString();
        }
        if (rdr[2] != null)
        {
            string PARAM3 = rdr[2].ToString();
        }
        if (rdr[3] != null)
        {
            string PARAM4 = rdr[3].ToString();
        }
    }
}
rdr.Close();
```

the procedure returns something like this:

```
SELECT 
    'value1' AS 'PARAM1', 
    199 AS 'PARAM2', 
    'value2' AS 'PARAM3', 
    'value3' AS 'PARAM4'
RETURN 0
```

..but that solution is not satisfying to get a param by name or by type.

Comment: Do you really mean return parameters, meaning the parameter direction is `ReturnValue`? Or are you talking about the result set?

Comment: It is rdr[name] instead of a number.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working the way you want? I can tell you that if the reader has more than one row you will overwrite the `PARAMx` variables on each loop iteration and that is probably not what you would want.

Comment: @UweKöhler you don't need a parameter you can access it by rdr["PARAM1"] directly

Comment: the access with parameter name:  rdr[name]  doesn't work because the name is unknown

Answer (score 1):

Use the parameter name and get the value like this:

```
Param4 = rdr["@YourOutputParameter"].Value
```

May be you need to cast it to the type that you expected, for string use:

```
Param4 = rdr["@YourOutputParameter"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: the access with parameter name doesn't work for me because the name is unknown. May be because it's not defined inside SQL as out parameter?

Comment: @UweKöhler make sure that the name of the column that you try to get the value or the column alias exist in the columns returned in the select statement